# Docker, Vagrant, CentOS 7, cannot start

Tags: docker, vagrant, centos7

The `/var/log/messages` log is below

```
Aug  3 04:27:54 localhost lvm[3169]: Thin centos-docker--pool is now 100% full.
Aug  3 04:27:54 localhost lvm[3169]: Insufficient free space: 1 extents needed, but only 0 available
Aug  3 04:27:54 localhost lvm[3169]: Failed to extend thin centos-docker--pool.
```

And the systemctl status log is below:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2015-08-03 04:22:52 UTC; 6min ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 7577 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $ADD_REGISTRY $BLOCK_REGISTRY $INSECURE_REGISTRY (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 7577 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 03 04:22:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Aug 03 04:22:52 localhost.localdomain docker[7577]: time="2015-08-03T04:22:52Z" level=info msg="+job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)"
Aug 03 04:22:52 localhost.localdomain docker[7577]: time="2015-08-03T04:22:52Z" level=info msg="Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)"
Aug 03 04:22:52 localhost.localdomain docker[7577]: time="2015-08-03T04:22:52Z" level=fatal msg="Shutting down daemon due to errors: error intializing graphdriver: Unable to take ownership of... data blocks"
Aug 03 04:22:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 03 04:22:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 03 04:22:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

And here is the `lsblk` result:

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# lsblk
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                             8:0    0  9.9G  0 disk 
â”œâ”€sda1                          8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
â””â”€sda2                          8:2    0  9.4G  0 part 
  â”œâ”€centos-root               253:0    0  8.4G  0 lvm  /
  â”œâ”€centos-swap               253:1    0 1016M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  â”œâ”€centos-docker--pool_tmeta 253:2    0   12M  0 lvm  
  â”‚ â””â”€centos-docker--pool     253:4    0   16M  0 lvm  
  â””â”€centos-docker--pool_tdata 253:3    0   16M  0 lvm  
    â””â”€centos-docker--pool     253:4    0   16M  0 lvm  
sr0                            11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
sr1                            11:1    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: I found the solution,  after install it  then reinstall docker is  ok now.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438648/cant-install-docker-on-centos-7-running-on-vagrant

Comment: I've had issues with the thin pool's meta data pool running out of space. Are you using dm.thinpooldev settings? Also, how was your thin pool created? What is the result of sudo docker info What is the result of sudo lvs

Comment: No. the problem above is due to my `lvm logic volume` is too small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem maybe there is not enough `lvm` space to use. It was only to be allocated `16MB`.
The solution is to resize the `logic volume` of `centos-docker-pool`